# Validation AZURE Access token in Resource Server

Tags: rest, azure, spring-boot, java-8, oauth-2.0

I have a scenario in which I need access token from Azure AD for all my resource server API's since it requires to call to Graph API's. As per my knowledge we cannot invoke Graph API using Id Token and it requires Access Token instead. So after successful Authentication from azure SSO, the UI sends access token as bearer header in all my Spring Boot 2 REST API's.

My question is how can I validate the access token against my REST API's. do we have any out of box feature for doing that or do we need to implement custom validation against the access tokens.

Lets say if I have a REST API called get all user groups like as shown below

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public GroupDetailsResponse getAllUserGroups() {
 .....
}
```

How can I implement the @PreAuthorize using access token.

Answer (score 0):

Validating the token consists of a series of steps, and if any of these fails, then the request must be rejected. Here is the lists all the validations that your API should perform:

•   Check that the JWT is well formed

•   Check the signature

•   Validate the standard claims

•   Check the Application permissions (scopes)

For implementing custom validation you need to do the following:

1. Parse the Jwt

In order to parse the JWT you can either manually implement all the checks as described in the specification [RFC 7519 > 7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-7.2) Validating a JWT, or use one of the libraries listed in the Libraries for Token Signing/Verification section of JWT.io.

For example, if your API is implemented with Node.js and you want to use the node-jsonwebtoken library, then you would call the jwt.verify() method. If the parsing fails then the library will return a JsonWebTokenError error with the message jwt malformed.

2. Check the signature algorithm

The API needs to check if the algorithm, as specified by the JWT header (property alg), matches the one expected by the API. If not, the token is considered invalid and the request must be rejected.

To check if the signature matches the API's expectations, you have to decode the JWT and retrieve the alg property of the JWT header.

Alternatively, you can use one of the libraries listed in the Libraries for Token Signing/Verification section of [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/).

3. Validate the claims

Once the API verifies the token's signature, the next step is to validate the standard claims of the token's payload. The following validations need to be made:

•   Token expiration: The current date/time must be before the expiration date/time listed in the exp claim (which is a Unix timestamp). If not, the request must be rejected.

•   Token issuer: The iss claim denotes the issuer of the JWT. The value must match the one configured in your API. For JWTs issued by Auth0, iss holds your Auth0 domain with a https:// prefix and a / suffix: https://YOUR_DOMAIN/. If you are using the custom domains feature, the value will instead be in the following format: https:///.

•   Token audience: The aud claim identifies the recipients that the JWT is intended for. For JWTs issued by Auth0, audholds the unique identifier of the target API (field Identifier at your API's Settings). If the API is not the intended audience of the JWT, it must reject the request.

Here is JWT library for JAVA where you can use verify(token) method for validating.

https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt